# The request can be optimized?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this SQL request:

```
SELECT 
    m.id, 
    IF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN bc.start_date AND bc.expiration_date, FALSE, TRUE) AS hasFreeAccount, 
    CONCAT(e.id, ' - ', e.name) AS establishment, 
    bc.start_date, 
    bc.expiration_date
FROM establishment e 
    LEFT JOIN establishment_owner eo ON e.id = eo.establishment
    LEFT JOIN member m ON eo.member = m.id 
    LEFT JOIN business_command bc ON m.id = bc.member
WHERE eo.member = 103
    AND (bc.start_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() OR bc.start_date is NULL)
    AND (bc.id NOT IN (
        SELECT bc.id 
        FROM member m 
            LEFT JOIN business_command bc on m.id = bc.member 
            INNER JOIN establishment_owner eo on m.id = eo.member 
        WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > bc.expiration_date 
            AND eo.member IN (SELECT m.id FROM member m LEFT JOIN business_command bc ON m.id = bc.member HAVING COUNT(m.id) > 1)
    ) OR bc.id IS NULL);
```

With this Explain plan:
[image]

The request works, I just want to know if I can optimize it.

Comment: Well, since the `WHERE` clause doesn't allow `eo.member` to be NULL, the `LEFT JOIN` to `establishment_owner` could be made an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your original query, I see that the only static `WHERE` clause is

```
WHERE eo.member = 103
```

This being the case, you should make `establishment_owner` the main table in the query:

```
SELECT 
    m.id, 
    IF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN bc.start_date AND bc.expiration_date, FALSE, TRUE) AS hasFreeAccount, 
    CONCAT(e.id, ' - ', e.name) AS establishment, 
    bc.start_date, 
    bc.expiration_date
FROM
    establishment_owner eo
    LEFT JOIN establishment e ON eo.establishment = e.id
    LEFT JOIN member m ON eo.member = m.id 
    LEFT JOIN business_command bc ON m.id = bc.member
WHERE eo.member = 103
    AND (bc.start_date <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() OR bc.start_date is NULL)
    AND (bc.id NOT IN (
        SELECT bc.id 
        FROM member m 
            LEFT JOIN business_command bc on m.id = bc.member 
            INNER JOIN establishment_owner eo on m.id = eo.member 
        WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() > bc.expiration_date 
            AND eo.member IN (SELECT m.id FROM member m LEFT JOIN business_command bc ON m.id = bc.member HAVING COUNT(m.id) > 1)
    ) OR bc.id IS NULL);
```

In other words, `LEFT JOIN` from `establishment_owner` instead of `establishment`.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `LEFT JOIN` unless you expect the 'right' table to have missing rows.
- `IN ( SELECT ... )` performs poorly.  Use either `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` or `JOIN`.
- `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` performs even more poorly.  Use either `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` or `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.
- `OR` is hard to optimize.  Ponder ways to avoid it.